# specific version of pivot table in R (without aggregation)

Tags: r, dataframe, pivot

Lets take data.frame:

```
df <- data.frame(
  name = c(rep('John',5), rep('Mike',5), rep('Julia',5)),
  date = rep(c(Sys.Date()+c(1:5)),3),
  text = c(LETTERS[1:15])
)
```

I would like to get table like on the picture bellow

[image]

I know how to do it if column text would be integer (dcast) but for character I am powerless

Comment: still dcast `dcast(df, name ~ format(date, '%d.%m.%Y'), value.var = 'text')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
df %>%
  mutate(date = format(date, '%d.%m.%Y')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = text)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 6
#>   name  `13.04.2021` `14.04.2021` `15.04.2021` `16.04.2021` `17.04.2021`
#>   <chr> <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>        <chr>       
#> 1 John  A            B            C            D            E           
#> 2 Mike  F            G            H            I            J           
#> 3 Julia K            L            M            N            O
```

Answer (score 1):

The tidyverse version

```
library(tidyr)
df %>% pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = text)
```